# Calculate average elevation value in LAS files in a specific area

Tags: arcmap, lidar, statistics, las, lastools

I need to calculate the average elevation and its standard deviation of some buildings and parts of roads using LAS files.

I want to be able to consider only the points that are within a polygon in a shapefile. My LAS files have a point space of 0.7 meters and the area covered by each tile is 1500 meters X 1500 meters, but the buildings that I want to consider have small areas of 190 meters X 50 meters.

I only want to have the average elevation of the points that are within the purple box

[image: I only want to have the average elevation of the points that are within the purple box]

Comment: What software or API do you intend to use? If it is ArcMap as per the tag do you have 3d analyst and spatial analyst extension? If so https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/las-to-raster-function.htm to convert LAS to average raster then Zonal Statistics https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics.htm or Zonal Statistic as Table for multiple polygons can calculate the mean of the mean raster from the LAS records with only a little inaccuracy.

Comment: ArcGIS Desktop and Pro with 3d analyst extension have a tool called Extract LAS https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/extract-las.htm which will allow you to extract just the LAS within then use LAS dataset statistics https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/las-dataset-statistics.htm to generate usable statistics *but* I would only use this method on a very small sample area. This would be much more accurate but definitely slower, perhaps something that could be done in a model or script if you have a lot of buildings of interest.

Comment: Would a spatial join aggregating the elevation by average not work for this?

Comment: I am using ArcMap,  and I tried Extract LAS but it does not pick the points correctly. In some polygons it extracts all the points correctly but there other polygons that I know should have points but the tool do not capture any point.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with spatial joint in this case